# How to mitigate race condition when concurrently calling a function involving a write operation that depends on a read operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, transactions, race-condition

I have a simple collection called Ledger with the following schema

```
Ledger: {
  account: String,
  amount: Number // actually an integer
}
```

I have a function that debits an account based on the balance remaining on that account:

```js
const debit = async (account_to_be_debited, amount_to_be_debited) => {
  let transactions = await Ledger.find({ account: account_to_be_debited })
  
  let balance = transactions.reduce((accumulated_balance, transaction) => {
    accumulated_balance += transaction.amount
    return accumulated_balance
  }, 0)
    
  if (balance < amount_to_be_debited) {
    throw new Error('insufficient funds')
  }
  
  let new_transaction = await Ledger.create({ account: account_to_be_debited, amount: -amount_to_be_debited })
  
  return new_transaction._id
}
```

now I want to be able to do something like this in an async environment:

```js
// the first debit
debit('account_1', 100).then(id => console.log(id))

// another debit
debit('account_1', 200).then(id => console.log(id))
```

My concern is that if the two debit operations occur concurrently, there's a risk of a double spend as both debit operations will check against an identical balance. This wouldn't be a problem if instead I waited for one debit transaction to finish before executing the next

```js
let debit_1 = await debit('account_1', 100)
let debit_2 = await debit('account_1', 200)
```

I am aware that with the release of mongodb 4.0 I can use transactions, but I'm not sure if transactions are executed synchronously by mongodb. If they are, then I can be certain that every subsequent transaction would read the changes reflected by the most recently committed transaction and that reads across transactions can't happen concurrently, because transactions can't happen concurrently.

So my question is: are mongodb transactions suitable for my use case, specifically for mitigating the race condition I described above?

If not, what are the possible ways I can go about this. I'm writing this application in node js and I am currently using mongoose to model and interact with a mongodb replica-set.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The concurrency's behavior of a mongodb transaction is customizable according to the doc https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/causal-consistency-read-write-concerns/

Comment: hi @Radar155 thanks for the reference. The information on that page seems a little too cryptic for me. Do you know which of the scenarios mentioned in the documentation page is suitable for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo transactions are generally used to make sure that a set of updates/inserts across multiple collections (or a single collection!) either all succeed or all fail, which doesn't sound like the use case that you're describing. Instead, you want to make sure that if there are two updates, one of them will fail, which is something that you should try and handle on the database-side (rather than with application code).

You can write your update operation in a way that will fail if it's not a valid update: `db.ledger.updateOne({account: 'account_1', amount: {$gte: 200}}, {$inc: { amount: 200 }})`.

The `$gte` will ensure that this operation will only take place on a document that meets your criteria & you can see whether or not the update succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This option would be a little tricky in my case since the balance is not exactly stored on the database. The ledger collection is a record of all transactions, so getting the balance involves aggregating over all of the transactions made by a given account. And I am not updating the balance, but simply creating a new transaction under the account.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, you could use a similar pattern to implement application-side "locking" of that row. You could create a "lock" by running a query like `db.ledger.updateOne({account: 'account_1', lockedBy: {$exists: false}}, {$set: {lockedBy: processId}})` and then ensure that all your updates respect that `lockedBy` field & wait. It's a pretty ugly solution, but I think it'd accomplish what you want.

Comment: Would findAndModify be better than updateOne? "MongoDB we recommend using the findAndModify command for this scenario. This command is atomic and thus lock the document for a status change." https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/locking-documents-in-mongo/6865

Comment: `findAndModify` is better if you want the document. `updateOne` is atomic